# Check programmatically Reporting Services's role with SQL query and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, permissions

I create a setup with WiX Toolset which use UAC.

I must check programmatically if Windows User is a Content Manager of Reporting Services instance because the windows user must can

- publish, update and delete reports, folder and datasource
- add new role to other windows accounts

I have:

- Reporting Services instance name
- Reporting Serveces database name
- Web Service URL of Reporting Services instance

Using WiX I can use C#, SQL query...

With SQL Server I just use

```
IS_SRVROLEMEMBER
```

to check Windows Account's role on SQL Server instance

How I can check programmatically the role in Reporting Services?
Maybe using sql query on Reporting Services's tables?
Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are after but these table contain users and their roles.

For example

```
select 
    u.* ,
    r.*
 from ReportServer..Users u
    join ReportServer..PolicyUserRole ur on u.UserID = ur.UserID
    join ReportServer..Roles r on ur.RoleID = r.RoleID
    where  UserName like '%john%'
```

Comment: Thanks but I search a query/code that works also
- John is under a domain group
- and only this domain group is Content Manager

Comment: That did the trick! To get all users and their permissions remove the last line in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code

```
   select U.UserName, R.RoleName,R.Description, C.Path, C.Name 
    from dbo.PolicyUserRole A
       inner join dbo.Policies P on A.PolicyID = P.PolicyID
       inner join dbo.Users U on A.UserID = U.UserID
       inner join dbo.Roles R on A.RoleID = R.RoleID
       inner join dbo.Catalog C on A.PolicyID = C.PolicyID
       WHERE  UserName like '%Ben%'
```